# High CPU load in sub-child process

Tags: java, processbuilder

I'm working on a java program that run a batch file using a `ProcessBuilder`.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("pathToMyBatch.bat");
            Process process = processBuilder.start();
            StreamReader fluxSortie = new StreamReader(process.getInputStream());
            StreamReader fluxErreur = new StreamReader(process.getErrorStream());
            new Thread(fluxSortie).start();
            new Thread(fluxErreur).start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static class StreamReader implements Runnable {

        private final InputStream inputStream;

        StreamReader(InputStream inputStream) {
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        private BufferedReader getBufferedReader(InputStream is) {
            return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            BufferedReader br = getBufferedReader(inputStream);
            String ligne = "";
            try {
                while ((ligne = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(ligne);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

`StreamReader` class is a `Runnable`that wait for inputs and print every read line.

Thebatch file launches an other java application simply by calling `java -classpath...`, and do other stuff related (and unrelated) to this application.

I can't modify this batch.

To make it clear: 
Program `A` launches batch file `B` that launches application `C`

When I run the batch file `B` directly from windows, the java application `C` barely use more than 2% of CPU. But when I run it through my java program `A`, `C` consumes 25% of CPU load (1 full core). 
In both cases, the batch execution charge on CPU is ~0%.

I guess that's due to the output and error streams of the java application that are not handled correctly.

Am I right? How could I fix this? Is there any way to get the sub-child (the child of the process) process stream?

Comment: Your title is wrong.  The high load is in the Java application, not the child process.

Comment: that's why I wrote `sub-child process`.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain yourself clearly.  The phrase "sub-child process" is not meaningful.

Comment: What happens if you remove System.out.println() ?

Comment: How many lines writes program C? Can you measure performance of C? May by program C spends time on println when started as standalone app and work at full speed when you use pipe.

Comment: I suspect that you should redesign IPC and use sockets to transfer data.

Comment: `C` only write ~20 lines. If i remove the `println`, I get the same issue. @John what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

> I guess that's due to the output and error streams of the java application that are not handled correctly.
>
> Am I right?

Possibly.  But that is a very vague description of what (you think) is happening.

I suspect that the problem is in your `StreamReader` class.  For example:

- it could be reading the stream without buffering,
- it could be polling the stream,
- it could be processing (or accumulating) the output in an inefficient way,
- or something else.

If you want a better answer, we really need to see the code of that class.

---

I suspect that it is the `System.out.println` calls.

Or perhaps it is that the child Java application is writing its output without buffering.

Comment: I removed it and tried to use a proper logger or to simply discard it. Still got the same issue